# How to write a table with hyperlinks in officedown powerpoint with R?

Tags: r, r-markdown, powerpoint, officedown

I can print my data with gt table and create hyperlinks for different cells, as shown below by knitting an HTML file:

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)
raw_dat <- mtcars[1:15, ] %>% rownames_to_column(var = "id") %>% select(id, mpg)
df <- tibble(
  name = raw_dat$id,
  link =  'https://www.cars.com//')

df %>%
  mutate(link = sprintf('<p><a href = "%s">%s</a>', link, raw_dat$mpg),
         link = map(link, gt::html)) %>%
  gt
```

I want to print the same output to a powerpoint slide and preserve the links. I understand that I cannot use 'ph_with' with an object of class "c('gt_tbl', 'list')". So I was wondering what else I can do to print a table with hyperlinks in powerpoint.

```
NEW <- read_pptx("Presentation1.pptx") %>%
  add_slide(., layout = "Blank", master = "Office Theme") %>%
    ph_with(raw_dat, 
            location = ph_location(left = 0, top = 0, width = 13.33, height = 7.5))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution with flextable that is supported by officer.

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)
library(officer)

raw_dat <- mtcars[1:15, ] %>% rownames_to_column(var = "id") %>% select(id, mpg)
df <- tibble(name = raw_dat$id, link =  'https://www.cars.com//')

ft <- flextable(df) %>% 
  mk_par(j = "link", value = as_paragraph(hyperlink_text(x = name, url = link))) %>% 
  autofit()

read_pptx() %>%
  add_slide() %>%
  ph_with(ft, location = ph_location_type()) %>% 
  print(target = "toto.pptx")
```

[image]

PS: I am not sure that I answer the question as it is generated with officer, not officedown, but your example is not a R Markdown example. I assumed you wanted to use officer.

Comment: Hi Dave, the officer solution will work as well. Does that mean the PPT template gets defined in the YAML?

Comment: With officer, there is no yaml to define